# sshd daemon not running ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ssh, services, openssh, sshd

The sshd daemon is not running on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04). I have repeatedly re-installed the openssh server and rebooted.

I get no output to this command:

```
ps -A | grep sshd
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo start ssh`?

Comment: `ssh start/running, process 16431`

Comment: there is no need to purge openssh-server. After reinstallig sshd daemon will not run. check the permission of /var/run/sshd. It must be owned by root and not group or world writable.
change permission chmod 755 /var/run/sshd.
It will work .

Answer (score 2):

Try removing it completely `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server`

And remove config dir `mv /etc/ssh /etc/ssh_old`

Then `sudo mkdir /etc/ssh`

Then install it again `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! It ended up being that I needed to reinstall openssh-server. I ensured that the ssh was renamed to ssh_old, and I created a new ssh directory. I also had to ensure that any computer I used to remotely access this computer had its known_hosts file in the .ssh directory moved or deleted entirely.

This following website helped me find the solution (the website offers 3 solutions, I did solutions 1 & 3 which finally fixed it).

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed-error-and-solution/